# Proving $A\subset B\implies |A|\leq |B|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, cardinals

I would like to prove the following:

> Let $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$ be non-empty finite sets. Prove that if $A\subset B$, then $|A|\leq |B|$.

We are also given the following theorem:

> Theorem $1.31$: Let $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n<m$. Then there does not exist an injectve function $f:[m]\rightarrow[n]$.

Here we define $[n]=\lbrace 1,2,3,...,n\rbrace$.

Here is my attempt:

Assume that $|A|>|B|$. Then $A$ is in bijective correspondence with $[k_1]$ and $B$ is in bijective correspondence with $[k_2]$, with $k_1>k_2$. By theorem $1.31$ (this was previously given in the text), there exists no injection from $A$ to $B$. By the definition of $\subset$ every $x\in A$ satisfies $x\in B$. Define a function $1:A\rightarrow B$ such that $1(x)=x$. Because all $x\in A$ are in $B$, and each $x\in A$ is distinct by definition of a set, $1(x)$ is an injection into $B$. By definition of $A$ and $B$ there exist bijective functions $f_A:[k_1]\rightarrow A$ and $f_B:B\rightarrow [k_2]$. Thus, the function $g(x)=f_B(1(f_A(x)))$ is an injection $g:[k_1]\rightarrow [k_2]$ which by theorem $1.31$ cannot exist. This is a contradiction, and therefore our assumption $|A|>|B|$ must be false.

**I would like to know if this proof works, something feels off.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is fine but redundant.

By definition $|A|\leq|B|$ means that there exists a inyection $f:A\rightarrow B$. So, as $A\subseteq B$ then $1:A\rightarrow B$ is a inyection, then you get your conclution.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is quite simple, and you don't need a contradiction to do it.

Since $A\subset B$, we have that $\forall x\in A, x\in B$, and $\exists x\in B:x\notin A$.
$$\therefore |A|<|B|$$
QED

Comment: I have only a little experience in set theory, so this might be a naive question, but how do we know that $\exists x \in B : x \notin A \Rightarrow |A| < |B|$? It would seem that to prove this you need exactly the argument in Goedel's answer.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy The 'phrase' $A\subset B$ means, by definition, that every element in $A$ is also in $B$, yet there is at least $1$ element in $B$ that is NOT in $A$. Therefore, $|A|<|B|$ MUST be true.

Comment: this is exactly the argument you have in your answer, and does not really address my question; why must this be true? (I'm not saying it's not, I'm saying that showing this is an important part of the proof)

Comment: @DreamConspiracy Sorry I did not address your question in my last comment. Looking over it now makes me feel like an idiot. Anyway, my point is that the very definition of a strict subset implies the inequality in question. I guess the key fact of my proof is $\exists x\in B: x\notin A$ is not iteslf enough to imply $|A|<|B|$, yet $\exists x\in B: x\notin A$ along with $\forall x\in A, x\in B$ IS enough to imply the inequality. Thus by definition $A\subset B$ implies $|A|<|B|$.

Comment: @clatharatus again, I feel like there's a piece missing here. The definition of $A \subset B$ is that $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$. I don't see how this implies that there is an injective $f: A \to B$.